# Google maps directions with IvoryGoogleMapsBundle

Tags: symfony, session, subdomain

Within my application I manage to let the user pick two cities by using the autocomplete feature, and put markers on a google map I embed on the page. This part works great. 
Now I would like to dwar a driving route between those two markers, and I understood I have to use Directions. There is the main issue: Directions uses another CurlHttpAdapter: Widow instead of Geocoder. Those two cannot be used in same controller, so I am clueless on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution, by simply adding this line:

```
$directions = $this->get('ivory_google_map.directions');
```

Then you can use

```
$temp = $directions->route($from, $to);
$routes = $temp->getRoutes();
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $overviewPolyline = $route->getOverviewPolyline();
            $map->addEncodedPolyline($overviewPolyline);
        }
```

My only issue now is that this works only when I render a page, not when in a form where I use ajax to refresh the map, but that is another question I suppose.